# Calculus 1: a reference for exercises and solutions [pdf] request.

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I'm a student for computer science and among other things I'm learning calculus 1.

next week I have a midterm for the following subjects:

> - Limit of a sequence
> - series (including: convergent, Diverging)
> - Functions, function representation (including polar representation)
> - Limit of functions

I tried to Google for exercises and solutions but I didn't find something "real".

I'd like you to refer me for exercises with solutions (PDF). thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to [notes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8iaz6apnxg8g011/calc%201%20All%20notes%20copy.pdf) from a McGill calculus course. There you'll find the teachings of the class as well as fully solved problems. I didn't see any copy-write info, so it should be fine. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Many universities post practice exams on the departmental webpages, especially for lower-level undergraduate courses; is that real enough for you?

[Here's the link to Math 101 at Princeton](http://www.math.princeton.edu/undergraduate/course/MAT101), if you follow the various links you can also find the ones for the other 100 level courses.

[Here's the link to Iowa State](http://orion.math.iastate.edu/calculus/exams/exams.html)

[Here's the link to UC Irvine](http://www.math.uci.edu/undergraduate/courses/calculus-2a2b-resources)

[This is Google, answering your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=calculus+practice+midterm)